# Keep datatable sort between tabs in Shiny

Tags: r, sorting, shiny, dt

I'm trying to implement a shiny application where I have some datatables in a tabset panel, and this datatables have the same rows and columns. What I want to implement is that when the user sorts a column, if he changes the tab, the data will be sorted by the same column number than the first one. I have this application where I will try to implement it:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
app <- shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      # hides the default search functionality
      tags$style(
        #HTML(".dataTables_filter, .dataTables_info { display: none; }"),
        HTML(".shiny-input-container { display: none; }")
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(10, 
             ""
      ), 
      column(2,              
             # adding new page filter
             uiOutput("pageFilter")
      ),
      column(12,
       tabsetPanel(id = "tab",
         tabPanel('pressure',
                  DT::dataTableOutput('table1')
         ),
         tabPanel('mtcars',
                  DT::dataTableOutput('table2')
         )
       )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    global <- reactiveValues()

    observe({
      global$val <- input$table1_state$start / input$table1_state$length + 1
    })

    observe({
      global$val <- input$table2_state$start / input$table2_state$length + 1
    })

    output$pageFilter <- renderUI({
      numericInput("page", "Page", max(global$val,1), min = 1)
    })

    output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      iris
    }, options = list(pageLength = 15, stateSave = TRUE))

    output$table2 = DT::renderDataTable({
      mtcars
    }, options = list(pageLength = 15, stateSave = TRUE))

    # using new page filter
    observeEvent({input$page; input$tab}, {
      dataTableProxy("table1") %>% selectPage(global$val)
      dataTableProxy("table2") %>% selectPage(global$val)
    })
  }
)

runApp(app, launch.browser =  TRUE)
```

Any idea?

Comment: you mean, that if you sort in first tab by column 1 type ascending,...table in second tab will be also sorted by its column 1 type ascending ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `input$table1_state` variable you know already. The trick here is to define a datatable within the `renderDataTable()` and update the settings in there. I didnt see yet how the "shaking" is triggered, apparently the order changes very often, but i didnt get why yet.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
app <- shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      # hides the default search functionality
      tags$style(
        HTML(".dataTables_filter, .dataTables_info { display: none; }"),
        HTML(".shiny-input-container { display: none; }")
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(10, 
             ""
      ), 
      column(2,              
             # adding new page filter
             uiOutput("pageFilter")
      ),
      column(12,
             tabsetPanel(id = "tab",
                         tabPanel('pressure',
                                  DT::dataTableOutput('table1')
                         ),
                         tabPanel('mtcars',
                                  DT::dataTableOutput('table2')
                         )
             )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    global <- reactiveValues()

    observe({
      input$table1_state
      isolate({
        global$val <- input$table1_state$start / input$table1_state$length + 1
        if(!is.null(input$table1_state$order)){
          global$order <- input$table1_state$order
        }
      })
    })

    observe({
      input$table2_state
      isolate({
        global$val <- input$table2_state$start / input$table2_state$length + 1
        if(!is.null(input$table2_state$order)){
          global$order <- input$table2_state$order
        }
      })
    })

    output$pageFilter <- renderUI({
      numericInput("page", "Page", max(global$val, 1), min = 1)
    })

    output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(iris, options = list(
        order = global$order, stateSave = TRUE, pageLength = 15)
      )
    })

    output$table2 = DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(mtcars, options = list(
        order = global$order, stateSave = TRUE, pageLength = 15)
      )
    })

    # using new page filter
    observeEvent({input$page; input$tab}, {
      dataTableProxy("table1") %>% selectPage(global$val)
      dataTableProxy("table2") %>% selectPage(global$val)
    })

  }
)

runApp(app, launch.browser =  TRUE)
```